# Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema not working

Tags: 14.04, usb, webcam, microphone, camera

It just doesn't work on cheese.

From `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema
```

From `dmesg`, when re-connecting the cammera:

```
[ 2098.426935] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 2100.455781] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2100.491046] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=075d
[ 2100.491051] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2100.491054] usb 3-1: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM)
[ 2100.491057] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 2100.492564] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) (045e:075d)
[ 2100.499881] input: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input15
```

and on `dmesg`, when opening cheese:

```
[ 2283.440820] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR: unexpected command completion code 0x11.
[ 2283.440830] usb 3-1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 6
```

On cheese I see the following error (yes, I know, not very ilustrative):

```
There was an error playing video from the webcam
```

I read that the problem may be that the webcam requests too much bandwidth, but to be honest my knowledge of USB and cameras in general is null, and I can't find any work around.

The camera has a microphone on it as well. Not sure if is relevant. Having only the camera working is good enough, but of course I would like to have the microphone working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my computer has two usb hubs. I made sure that all ports from one hub were used for other things, and the second hub only had the camera connected. It worked around the problem, however not sure if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

cheese does not work initially. but after installing guvcview, cheese works fine.

sudo apt-get install guvcview

http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-06-19-microsoft-lifecam-cinema-720p-169